# I need an oracle Sql query to fetch the Product Name, Highest sales of the product in four years and the column name (year)

Tags: oracle

Table contains, productName, Year2000, Year2001, Year2002 etc. So, productName contains, 1. Milk, 2. Butter, 3. Curd etc, and the Year contains number of product sold like 200, 300 etc.Now I need oracle sql query to find the productName with highest sale in a year along with column name(like, year2000). 
Output should be like:
productName: Milk
Year2000: 200

The problem is how to get the particular year column Name like 'Year2002'

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the query which you have tried

Comment: select column_name, greatest(Year_2000, Year_2001, Year_2002 , Year_2003) from sale where table_name='sale';

Comment: am unable to get the particular year

Comment: Please add it your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help you...

```
Select product_name, year(date_column), max(sales)
from table_name
group by product_name, year(date_column)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think am not able to express properly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think am not able to express properly. Actually, table contains, productName, Year2000, Year2001, Year2002. So, productName contains, 1. Milk, 2. Butter, 3. Curd. and the Year contains number of product sold like 200.Now the query is to find the productName with highest sale in a year along with column name(like, year2000)

Comment: Can you put down a table with data and expected output

Comment: this question was asked in my recent interview.

A Table contains five columns/fields.
1. Product
2. 2000(Year)
3. 2001(Year)
4. 2002(Year)
5. 2003(Year)

Product has 4 rows/values
1. Milk
2. Butter
3. Paneer
4. Curd

Now, 2000(Year) contains number of sales. 
1. 200
2. 300
3. 400
4. 700

Similarly, 2001(Year), 2002(Year),2003(Year) also contains number of sales.
Please note, each year contains number of sales that products has made.


Now, Now, the question is to find the product with highest number of sales.

Comment: Output should display:
Highest number of sales of the Product by comparing  these 4 years

For eg, if Milk has highest number of sales in 2000(Year) then the output should be:
Product: Milk
2000(Year) : 200